# What's the ST_GEOMETRY type in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, shapes

Table Description is...

```
COLUMN NAME          /  DATA TYPE
------------------------------------------ 
MNUM                  VARCHAR2(33) 
ALIAS                 VARCHAR2(200)
REMARK                VARCHAR2(200)
NTFDATE               VARCHAR2(8)  
SGG_OID               INTEGER      
COL_ADM_SECT_CD       VARCHAR2(5)  
OBJECTID              INTEGER      
**SHAPE               ST_GEOMETRY**
```

Does anybody know about Spatial information processing?
First of all, One of column's type in oracle is "ST_GEOMETRY" .
What is this kind of type?
And how can we migrate these kind of data to other oracle databse system?

Answer (score 1):

ST_GEOMETRY is not native Oracle type. It is spatial type developed by esri and apparently it is installed on top of oracle database. I would assume that some ArcGIS products are using this database.

You can read more about this type in esri documentation. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/stgeometry-oracle.htm

The previous answer is misleading since it describes SDO Geometry which is another completely different spatial type developed by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

ST_GEOMETRY is a spatial data type.  The use of the data type along with other supported data types are part of Oracle database's spatial technology.  Apparently ST_GEOMETRY is also part of an ISO standard that Oracle supports.

You can migrate these objects and other data from Oracle database to database using data pump.

[Oracle Spatial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_sql_mm.htm)

[Oracle Spatial Data Pump](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22733/how-to-move-an-oracle-spatial-table-to-another-db)

Comment: Oh...Thank you very very much.^^ I'll read that article. Thank you.^^